# Terraform chef provisioner failing to write private key

Tags: chef-infra, terraform, private-key

When trying to create a aws ec2 instance using terraform, the code fails with chef provisioner. After it installs the chef client, it is writing the private key (client.pem) but it is failing giving error message, "you are not authorized for this action". After this knife client create also fails because the client.pem is not exist. The below is my terraform code.

```
  resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-07ebfd5b3428b6f4d"
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  subnet_id     = "subnet-09c4311dd01388e28"
  security_groups = ["sg-0cc3e7c431b859575"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name = var.instance_key
  tags = {
    Name = "chefclient"
  }
  provisioner "chef"{
     connection{
          type = "ssh"
          user = "ubuntu"
          host = aws_instance.web.public_ip
          private_key = file("/home/ubuntu/chefprovision/cptest.pem")
      }
      os_type = "linux"
      prevent_sudo = false
      client_options  = ["chef_license 'accept'"]
      environment = "_default"
      log_to_file = true
      fetch_chef_certificates = true
      node_name = "client1"
      server_url = "https://ec2-54-160-5-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com/organizations/cloudlego"
      recreate_client = true
      run_list = [""]
      user_name = "legoadmin"
      user_key = file("/home/ubuntu/chefprovision/legoadmin.pem")
      skip_register = true
      ssl_verify_mode = ":verify_none"
  }
}
```

Could someone help me, what am I missing ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full error output?

Comment: Are you cleaning up objects (node and client) on the Chef server in between terraform runs? If the key pair is dynamically generated, then any attempt after the first will fail when the public key from a previous iteration still exists on the Chef server.

Comment: Either sherenator has the proper guess, or your legoadmin user is not admin on the cloudlego organization and thus has no rights to create a node or client.